# XML response error: Invalid at the top level of the document

Tags: c#, xml, namevaluecollection

I am getting an error back and following the API manual I received on how to encode my request. Below is my request..

```
string url = "[My url to send request to]";

string xmlrequest = "<serv_request><head><securityContext><account>[account]</account><key>[my account key]</key></securityContext></head><body><username>[my user name]</username></body></serv_request>";

NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("xml", Server.UrlEncode(xmlrequest));


WebClient client = new WebClient();

byte[] byteresponse = client.UploadValues(url, nvc);

string xmlresponse = client.Encoding.GetString(byteresponse);
```

I am getting a response back with the error. Invalid at the top level of document.

Edit.. Adding the Instructions from the API Manual provided to me..

```
string url = " http://[domain_name]/_gateway/api/[filename].asp"; 

// formulate the XML request here 

string xmlrequest = "<serv_request>...</serv_request>";  

NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection(); 
nvc.Add("xml", Server.UrlEncode(xmlrequest)); 

WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
byte[] byteresponse = client.UploadValues(url, nvc); 

string xmlresponse = client.Encoding.GetString(byteresponse);
```

Comment: Start the string with the xml tag? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

Comment: Thanks your your reply, when trying this as... string xmlrequest = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><serv_request><head><securityContext><account>training</account><key>[my key code]</key></securityContext></head><body><username>[my user name]</username></body></serv_request>" I am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried including a XML namespace attribute on the beginning `<serv_request>` tag? Something like `<serv_request xmlns="{YourXMLNamepsace}">`

Comment: Yes I just tried that solution and got same response. The following is strait from the API manual for the service I am requesting....   string url = " http://[domain_name]/_gateway/api/[filename].asp"; 
// formulate the XML request here 
string xmlrequest = "<serv_request>...</serv_request>"; 
 
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection(); 
nvc.Add("xml", Server.UrlEncode(xmlrequest)); 
 
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
byte[] byteresponse = client.UploadValues(url, nvc); 
 
string xmlresponse = client.Encoding.GetString(byteresponse);

Comment: If your communicating with or making a web-service, I suggest you check out [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the server is not responding with a proper xml, it may be returning an empty string or any text that is not a well formed XML.

Try and capture the xml you are sending and use a tool like soapUI to send the request and see the response it gives to you.

Also maybe try this in stead of your last line of code:

string xmlresponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteresponse);

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this. Instead of passing a string with all the xml in it and using Server.UrlEncode I used the XmlWriter class and StringBuilder. All your replies were helpful and much appriciated, I would  up vote them but I cannot do that feature yet. Maybe this will help others in the future. Thanks

```
        XmlWriter writer;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
        writer.WriteStartElement("serv_request");
        writer.WriteStartElement("head");
        writer.WriteStartElement("securityContext");
        writer.WriteStartElement("account");
        writer.WriteString("MyAccountName");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("key");
        writer.WriteString("MyKey");
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //closes Key Element
        writer.WriteEndElement(); // closes securityContent
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //closes head
        writer.WriteStartElement("body");
        writer.WriteStartElement("username");
        writer.WriteString("MyUserName");
        writer.WriteEndElement(); // closes username
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //closes body
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //closes serv_request
        writer.Close();

        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();           
        nvc.Add("xml", sb.ToString());          

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        byte[] byteresponse = client.UploadValues(url, nvc);

        string xmlresponse = client.Encoding.GetString(byteresponse);
```

Comment: I'm also using the inquisiq api and this method worked for me too! Thank you for your help. Have you found a better way to do this yet?